# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'check'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to display db data on chart. But it occurs an error on run time. I tried to solve, but I can't. Any one can help me. Code is given below:

```
 public partial class chart4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=G:\vipin\graph\graph.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from check", con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        DataView source = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
        Chart1.DataSource = source;

        Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "name";
        Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "age";
        Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "address";
        Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "phno";
        Chart1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

source:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="name"></asp:Series>
                <asp:Series Name="age"></asp:Series>
                <asp:Series Name="address"></asp:Series>
                <asp:Series Name="phno"></asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
    </div>
```

Comment: Really really bad name for a table.... you should **avoid** all [reserved keywords for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) and do **NOT** use those as your table or column names!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that [`CHECK`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx) is a reserved word in T-SQL Server so wrap it in braces `[check]`

Answer (score 1):

`CHECK` is a *[reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)* in T-SQL. You need to use it with square brackets like `[check]`

As a general recomendation, don't use reserved keywords for your identifiers and object names in your database. The best solution is to change the name to a *non-reserved* word.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR:Msg 4, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 incorrect syntax near by
>   "check"

EG:

```
 ALTER TABLE OFFICE
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_OFFICE_SALARY CHECk (SALARY>=5000);
```

your check constraints is already executed  wrongly so you should change the executed constraints name